# How to make url with slug in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, web, laravel-5.4

Right now I am trying to do a Laravel url with slug. I have my main page where I show all categories:

```
<div class="panel-body">
      @foreach($categories as $category)
            <p><a href="{{ URL::to('test/' . $category->slug) }}">{{ $category->name }}</a></p>
      @endforeach
</div>
```

And now I want to go to a certain category page. I created routes:

```
Route::get('/test', 'FuelAccountingController@index')->name('fuel_accounting');
Route::get('/test/{slug}', 'FuelAccountingController@element');
```

And functions in controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = DB::table('fuel_accounting_categories')
        ->select('id', 'name', 'slug')
        ->get();

    return view('pages.fuel_accounting')->with('categories', $categories);
}

public function element($slug)
{
    $category = DB::table('fuel_accounting_categories')
        ->select('slug')
        ->where('slug', '=', $slug)
        ->first();

    return view('pages.fuel_accounting_element')->with('category', $category);
}
```

And when I am trying to reach a page (for example: laravel.dev/test/current_category) it does not work. Can someone explain me how to do that?

Error: Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. (1/1) NotFoundHttpException

**FIXED**

Comment: So, should the "test" class name start with an upper- or a lowercase "T"?

Comment: Your routes and the controller action look OK. Which suggests Laravel really cannot resolve the route, for some reason. Look for typos in the controller name, action name. Also, make sure no other route overwrites your slug route. Plus, try running `php artisan route:clear`. It's probably something obvious, meaning: hardest to spot ;)

Comment: `select("slug")->where("slug","=",$slug)` makes no sense. Why query the database for it when you already know what it is?

Comment: Can you please paste a screenshot  here of the error you getting ?

Comment: Could you post the error you are getting? In the meantime, If you haven't already, add this to the category model: public function getRouteKeyName(){return 'slug'; }.

Comment: Error: Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="panel-body">
      @foreach($categories as $category)
            <p><a href="{{URL::to('test/'.$category->name)}}">{{ $category->name }}</a></p>
      @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Problem not here, its not about that. Read again.